# input skipped during program execution Python/Pycharm

Tags: python

I'm (very) new to Python and after installing Pycharm, I notice that even with the simplest instructions, the execution of the program in the console doesn't let me enter anything when prompted by an input(); it just skips everything and end the program.

When I use debug and set points at the input however it works normally.

Does anyone of you encountered this issue before? Thanks in advance, cheers

Comment: No, it doesn't happen to me ever. I'm using PyCharm 5.0.1 with Python 2.7.x. Have you tried raw_input instead? Just a suggestion, it's not normal to use input due to it requires to enter a "valid" string, it means quoted

Comment: Not a semicolon at the end by the way ;)

Comment: @MaximilianoRios, `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3.x

Comment: I didn't know he was using Python 3.0. However I don't see why it could be happening, might be a compatibility issue?

Comment: Hey Maximiliano ! Thanks for the responses ! I guess I am SUPER new to Python... I found why it did that and it was because the option "run console afterwards" was checked. Just a configuration issue on my side... Thanks a lote anyway :)

Comment: And for the semicolon I guess I did it without even noticing it ;) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found why it did that and it was because the option "run console afterwards" was checked. Just a configuration issue on my side... Thanks a lote anyway :)